# Running a business in a D&D 4e game?

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, party

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any games that include a good rule system for running a business?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/are-there-any-games-that-include-a-good-rule-system-for-running-a-business)

My group is looking to set up a trading post in our game where we can sell our loot through, we were wondering what mechanics we would have to think about in order to achieve this.

i.e. costs or buying / leasing shop, employing staff security and then how to calculate income etc..  and also relevant information the DM might need to think of in order to do this.

Comment: Are you interested in all D&D editions or just 4e? Are you interested in other potential systems that you can house-rule in?

Comment: yea totaly, I only specified 4e in the fact that is currently what we are using to run out game.. but totally interested in other editions if they can offer more to our campaign.

Comment: Is this question what you were after: [Are there any games that include a good rule system for running a business?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/are-there-any-games-that-include-a-good-rule-system-for-running-a-business)

Comment: perfect.. thanks very much.. apparently I did not look hard enough :P sorry about that.

Comment: We're here to help. Voting to close :) Also, welcome to the site! :)