# What was this RPG that had rules for player-owned businesses?

Tags: product-identification

A few years ago I sat in on a campaign where the rules had a nice table for player-owned businesses. It had things like a bank, a bakery, a grocery store and maybe a saloon as well. I think it was an Old West RPG but maybe not.

The table had the cost to buy the business and some stats on how much profit it would make, based on die rolls for things like competition, location, weather maybe?

I've been searching for a while trying to find this again with no luck. Any chance this is ringing a bell for anyone?

Comment: There are several games with rules for downtime (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/are-there-any-games-that-include-a-good-rule-system-for-running-a-business)), we need a little more information.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm happy to provide what else I can recall. This was a fairly macro level rule set IIRC. It wasn't more than a page or two of rules at most. Almost everything was in the table that showed the type of business, what type of test roll to make to earn profit, and a couple of modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I have heard of that comes close are supplemental rules for the [Pathfinder](https://paizo.com/pathfinder) game.  I own the [Ultimate Campaign](https://paizo.com/products/btpy8vdl) book which has rules for [running a business](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/#TOC-Run-a-Business) as part of its [Downtime](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/) rules related to [Kingdom Building](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building/):

> #### Run a Business
>
> If you have a building and that building generates any kind of
> capital, you can spend 1 day of downtime working at your
> building—increasing its productivity by inspiring your employees to
> work harder, using your expertise to get more done, or using your fame
> to attract more customers. This counts as using downtime to earn
> capital (see [Gaining Capital](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/#TOC-Gaining-Capital)), but you gain a +10 bonus on your check.
>
> The capital you generate must be a kind that your building can
> generate. For example, an inn that generates gp and Influence can
> generate only those two currencies using this downtime activity; you
> can’t use it to generate Goods, Labor, or Magic just because you’re
> personally running it for the day. You must earn capital acquired in
> this way as normal.

These are optional; the Gamemaster does not have to include [Kingdom Building](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/kingdom-building/) in the game.

Comment: Id like to point out that the kingdom building rules *can* be related to downtime, but downtime is entirely independent of kingdom building, as they were written by different people.

Comment: Thanks for this info and I may use it but this isn't what I'm remembering from the other game I played.